# Не могу клонировать репозиторий(

Tags: git, git-bash

При клонированиии репозитория выходит очень нехорошая вещь(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-то уже встречал такую проблеиу и соответственно решил)
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вы клонируете репозиторий используя ssh? Попробуйте https. Это решит проблему.
Причин почему у вас не выходит склонировать используя SSH может быть несколько. Вероятно у вас нет ключей

Comment: у меня есть ключ. Какие еще могут причины? Сервер рабочий может не пропускать SSh keys?

Comment: @vladtrokhanovsky так а через https все заработало, все ок?

Comment: Да. конечно! Я же вам галочку поставил. Хочу понять что не так сделал.

Comment: Ну тогда возможные причины такие: 1)SSH конфигурация - нужно проверить что SSH сгенерирован и добавлен корректно. 2)Сеть - какой-то фаерволл блочит или ограничения стоят какие-то.  Остальные причины, наверно, отпадают, так как у вас удалось по https склонировать. Кроме того, "kex_exchange_identification"  - ошибка связана с алгоритмом обменов ключами. Можете использовать разные алгоритмы с сервером. И поэтому получаете ошибку. Алгоритм который вы используете можете найти у себя в конфиг файле. ~/.ssh/config

Comment: bash: /h//.ssh/config: No such file or directory. Вот такой ответ я получил при вводе команды. Это важно? Я считал что скопировать содержимое .pub файла и вставить в настроики github это все(